# How to filter ForeignKey set icontains?

Tags: django

models.py

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=20)

class BModel(models.Model):
    a_model = models.ForeignKey(AModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=20)
```

Let say I have AModel object: `a_object`

And also I have BModel objects: 
`{'a_model': a_object, 'text': '111'}, 
{'a_model': a_object, 'text': '222'}, 
{'a_model': a_object, 'text': '333'}`

views.py

```
a_models = AModel.objects.filter(Q(bmodel__text__icontains=search_word))[:10]
```

The problem is that if `search_word` is `'111'`, It seems to be working well but `search_word` is `'222'` or `'333'`, then it cannot find `a_object`.

I think that `bmodel__text__icontains=search_word` means `'only one' bmodel__text__icontains=search_word`,
 not `'all' bmodel__text__icontains=search_word`.

How can I do `filter 'all' bmodel__text__icontains=search_word`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use exactly same model and data you have.

```
>>> a_models = AModel.objects.filter(Q(bmodel__text__icontains='222')).values('content')
>>> a_models
<QuerySet [{'content': 'a_object'}]>
>>> a_models = AModel.objects.filter(Q(bmodel__text__icontains='333')).values('content')
>>> a_models
<QuerySet [{'content': 'a_object'}]>
```

It return expected result.

I think you may mess something. 
Check again!

Answer (score 1):

You can chain your queries using `Q`. For example you can do:

```
$> complex_query = Q(bmodel__text__icontains='222') | Q(bmodel__text__icontains='333')
$> AModel.objects.filter(complex_query)
```

Or better:

```
$> elms = ["222", "333"]
$> complex_query = Q()
$> for elm in elms:
       complex_query |= Q(bmodel__text__icontains=elm)
$> AModel.objects.filter(complex_query)
```

You can find more informations in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)